# Kudu on Azure Webapp causes an "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed." exception

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Since yesterday (2016-02-11 18:32 EST), we get this mysterious error in our Azure Webapps' "New Relic" monitoring logs. It seems to happens every 5 minutes We have five applications, all were deployed yesterday around that exact time, but the deployment process it the same as before...

The applications are all functional. I do not know where this error comes from, but the Stack trace mentions `Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceModule.OnBeginRequest`

```
Error message
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Stack trace
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Web.Util.UriUtil.BuildUriImpl(String scheme, String serverName, String port, String path, String queryString, Boolean useLegacyRequestUrlGeneration)
at System.Web.Util.UriUtil.BuildUri(String scheme, String serverName, String port, String path, String queryString)
at System.Web.HttpRequest.BuildUrl(Func`1 pathAccessor)
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Url()
at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceModule.TryConvertSpecialHeadersToEnvironmentVariable(HttpRequestWrapper request)
at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceModule.OnBeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

[image: New Relic Error]

Any ideas what is causing this? Is it a Kudu / Azure issue? Can **I** do anything about it?

Comment: While there _is_ a legitimate reason and resolution, it's now obsolete (as it was a transient glitch).

Comment: It is, but I would still keep it as it still informs users about interactions and potential errors that can happen with Kudu and Azure Webapps. But that's just me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was indeed a new build of Kudu yesterday that caused this regression (build `51.50211.2078`). When it was found, and additional build was deployed (build `51.50212.2079`) to address it. However, it doesn't take effect until the site is restarted.

Please try restarting your site and confirm that the issue is gone. If you go to the Kudu home page, you can confirm the version before and after the restart.

Comment: It looks like this regressed again in `53.50324.2154.0`

Comment: That's strange, as I don't think anything has changed. DO you still have a repro? Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelTeperand if you need to provide more details, please open an issue on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu